# List of hashmaps in R

Tags: python, r, list, dictionary, hashmap

Im trying to make a list of hashes in R but I haven't figured it out yet.

I know in python I could do

```
d1 = { id: 1, name: 'ada' }
d2 = { id: 2, name: 'bob' }
users = list()

users.append(d1)
users.append(d2)
```

Is there a way I could do something like that in R?
Other option could be just a list of lists and accessing them by index.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific use-case, it might be easier to use a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
        id = c(1, 2),
        name = c("ada", "bob"),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The value can be referenced as:

```
df$name[df$id == 1]   # answer "ada"
```